# Sorting Macro not functioning properly

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro to cut and paste rows from one sheet ("New Providers - FPPE") into multiple sheets based on a column (H). When I first used it, it was working well, but when I have added additional data to the sorting sheet ("New Providers - FPPE") it is not fully functioning. The macro continues to cut the rows from "New Providers - FPPE" but the rows fail to populate onto the sheets. I have no idea where the rows are going. Does anyone have any insight as to what could be happening? I'm very new to writing macros so any help is appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fr33M4cro()

Dim sh33tName As String
Dim custNameColumn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim stRow As Long
Dim customer As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetExist As Boolean
Dim sh As Worksheet

sh33tName = "New Providers - FPPE"
custNameColumn = "H"
stRow = 7

Set sh = Sheets(sh33tName)

For i = sh.Range(custNameColumn & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To stRow Step -1
    customer = sh.Range(custNameColumn & i).Value
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If StrComp(ws.Name, customer, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sheetExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If sheetExist Then
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
    Else
        InsertSheet customer
        Set ws = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
    End If
    Reset sheetExist
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CopyRow(i As Long, ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByRef ws As Worksheet, custNameColumn As String)
Dim wsRow As Long
wsRow = ws.Range(custNameColumn & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


ws.Rows(wsRow).EntireRow.Value = sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub


Private Sub Reset(ByRef x As Boolean)
x = False
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSheet(shName As String)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = shName
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you read the description of the `macros` tag? It does not belong here.

Comment: Do you have any chart sheets in your workbook?

Comment: I have inserted tables in the sheets in order to filter the sorted information. Would that affect functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change your `InsertSheet` sub to a function that returns a reference to the inserted worksheet:

```
Function InsertSheet(shName As String) As Worksheet
    Set InsertSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    InsertSheet.Name = shName
End Function
```

then change this part of the code:

```
    InsertSheet customer
    Set ws = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
```

to this:

```
    Set ws = InsertSheet(customer)
    CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
```

Comment: It's still cutting the row, but not inserting it anywhere.

Comment: Unless you're getting an error, it **is** going somewhere. Have you tried pressing Ctrl+End on one of the sheets where you think the data ought to be?

Comment: Ah, that's helpful. Thank you!